# What is the best method to use an exFAT USB between Windows and Linux without causing errors on the disk?

Tags: usb, ssd, ubuntu

I have a 2TB USB for transferring files between two systems. Everything worked fine, until I gave it accidentally a transfer in Ubutuntu 22, too big to swallow. Windows cannot repair the disk. I see differences on the disk:
Windows: can see the files and has hidden files: FOUND.000 and 'System volume Information'. However, in Ubuntu: FOUND.000 is visible, but not accessible; 'System Volume Information is visible and accessible.

On Ubuntu, I have two file managers. One can access the disk, and the other can't (Thunar File Manager). Also, the program exFatprogs can't access the disk either. I believe this is because of the FOUND.000 map.

I would like to delete the FOUND.000 directory, while not corrupting the disk any further. This directory throws an Input/output error. It was not on the disk when it was new.